# Super Talent Express DUO Extremely Slow In USB Legacy Boot Mode

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo-laptop

I have lenovo G560 and tried new thumbdrive with booting from it. It is extremely slow! What could have taken 1 minute, will take 30 minutes on this thumbdrive. What can be done here?

I booted from SanDisk and everything was fast. Is it problem with Super Talent?

Comment: I assume Legacy = USB 1.0, so you've got maybe 11mbit bandwidth to play with?